# Woocommerce Backend Search by Title and SKU

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, search, sql

Good morning,
i'm trying to extend backend product search by using this function without success.

**This snippet works only in Title and i need to add also in Metakey SKU.**

I have tried extend by using post_join and post_where as in this example
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join
but i'm not expert on queries.

Please anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance.

```
function __search_by_title_only( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb,$typenow,$pagenow;

    if ( 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $search_ids = array();
        $terms      = explode( ' ', $_GET['s'] );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( is_numeric( $term ) ) {
                    $search_ids[] = $term;
                }

                if ( $search_term = $_GET['s'] ) {
                    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) ) . '%\'';
                }

        }
        return $where;  
    }
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
function search_by_sku( $search, &$query_vars ) {
        global $wpdb, $pagenow;
         if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || ! is_search() || ! isset( $query_vars ->query_vars['s'] ) || 'product' != $query_vars ->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
            return $search;
        }
        if(isset($query_vars->query['s']) && !empty($query_vars->query['s'])){
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                'post_type'       => 'product',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_sku',
                        'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            if(empty($posts)) return $search;
            $get_post_ids = array();
            foreach($posts as $post){
                $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
            }
            if(sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
                    $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
            }
        }
        return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_sku', 999, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. Just to let you know that I tried it but it generates a PHP warning: "Parameter 2 to search_by_sku() expected to be a reference, value given"